# Upload and download the files from server without giving the password

Tags: ssh, login, password, scp, remote

I want to download the file from server by using a cron job, so I need to use the `scp`  command without giving the password by keyword.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step is to generate a private-public key pair on the machine you copy from:

```
ssh-keygen
```

You can go with the defaults, and make sure you don't provide a password for usage. This can take a bit of time.

Second step, after the key generation has finished, is to copy the public key to the server using:

```
ssh-copy-id username@server
```

with the appropriate `username` and `server`. For this you need the password of `username`. If `username` doesn't have a password, you can copy the file with the public key via the root account, but it is much more easy to temporarily create a password for the account and use `ssh-copy-id`

Third step: test whether the installed public key is working using: `ssh username@server` or `scp somefile username@server:/var/tmp`

Fourth step: add a cron job (`crontab -e`) on the client machine:

```
15 23 * * * scp username@server:/path/on/server/downloadfile /local/destination
17 23 * * * scp /local/source/somefile username@server:/path/on/server/uploaddirectory
```

Which will copy the file `/path/on/server/downloadfile` every day at 11:15 PM from the server and two minutes later starts uploading `/local/source/somefile`

Things to consider:

- Depending on the security of the access to the client machine (where you are copying from) and where the unprotected private key is located, you should consider changing the `username` account so that it only allows `scp` and not `ssh`.
- If you copy the same file and the contents mostly change (e.g. appended to, not a complete rewrite), using `rsync` using the above ssh key pair) is more efficient.

Comment: Restricting the account is probably not doable, I expect there are other things to be done with this account beyond downloading the file. It's the key that should be restricted, with a `command=…` directive in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.