# I want to create a cron job that runs a command on a remote linux box using ssh but I want ssh to answer password

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, autocomplete

Thank you for the reply.This is not what I am after. The ssh from server 0 to (1,2,3) (no password) but a remote script on server (1,2 & 4 ) which starts a service/application needs a password for it to start. I want to be able to ssh and run this automatically, so ssh would expect a password from the remote script and answer with a password.–  Sal Allan32 mins ago

I want to create the cron job to run every Monday morning at 5AM.

Example

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server1 /app/pkg/solaris/start_script
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server2 /app/pkg/solaris/start_script
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server3 /app/pkg/solaris/start_script
```

When I run the above script from a cron job on a remote server every Monday morning, the application/start_script will prompt for a password to start the script. This is the application password. say password is BOB.

```
Please enter password:
```

Is there a way to answer the password prompt (by the start_script) without any manual interaction. The password prompt is for the application and not server I am ssh to. Its all trusted domain from one admin group.

Comment: You could try with an expect script. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101879/bash-expect-script-for-ssh

Comment: You are approaching this incorrectly, you should use passowrdless (i.e. public/private key) access for this as described [in this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174618/33055)

Comment: You don't really want to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.This is not what I am after. The ssh from A to (B,C,D) (no password) but a remote script on host (B,C & D ) which starts a service/application needs a password for it to start. I want to be able to ssh and run this automatically, so ssh would expect a password from the remote script and answer with a password.–  Sal Allan32 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

You just need a Secure SSH Connection Key, which will't ask the password.
You can do this all the host/server follow this below step

```
   #ssh-keygen -t rsa  
   #ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

now you can ssh to the remote server without password

It is very unsecured to mention password in any file.

Comment: If you give the generated key a passphrase, it will ask you for that when you use it. If you don't you have a private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` that is as insecure as a password in a file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.This is not what I am after. The ssh from A to (B,C,D) (no password) but a remote script on host (B,C & D ) which starts a service/application needs a password for it to start. I want to be able to ssh and run this automatically, so ssh would expect a password from the remote script and answer with a password.